# Create Github CI/CD Pipleline and deploy to Azure cloud Asp.net core and React Project

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have a repository of Fullstack Application created with ASP.NET core API and React FrontEnd. Both folders(Frontend and Backend) sit in the same Branch. I want to create a CI CD pipeline with Github actions for both frontend and backend and deploy to azure. Can I do this? How do I deploy both react and asp.net core API to azure? Is there any recommended approach to achieve this?

Comment: Hello Madushan, yes, it's possible to do it with Github Actions. Besides, Azure created many contents and actions that can help you get there. As I'm not very familiar with React and ASP.net I won't be able to give you more details, but here some references that might help: [Azure deploy with GHA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel) + [What is GHA for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/github-actions) + [Official Actions created by Azure](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=azure+)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I"ll check